# Would ROM hacking be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic, scope-expansion

This poor soul started a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100920/rom-hacking) which I believe is bound to die from lack of interest.

Meanwhile, we had some pretty in-depth questions with even more in-depth answers about programming the "retros". And we still suffer low daily question count.

Would it be okay to officially embrace the subject and invite the ROM hackers here?

Comment: We already have a "difference between these ROMs" question.

Comment: Would you mind creating the tag 'ROM-Hacking' SF? I've came here specifically for this and it would be great to be able to find these questions easily. (Note I literally just joined 5 minutes ago so don't know if the tag is warranted but my gut says 'ROM' which already exists won't be the same and there is probably enough _potential_ interest for it to warrant its own. Happy to wait till I've cut my teeth and earned the rep to do it myself though which will give me a chance to see if it is really needed.)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the usual cop-out applies:- It depends on the question.

Remember that reverse engineering commercial software is explicitly off-topic under the terms of service as:

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party

This has been recorded on [Superuser](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9293/questions-about-pirate-software-banned-in-superuser) and I would defer to that precedent.

Some old software has been made available publicly, as the original copyright holders have renounced copyright.  This abandonware would not violate these terms.

Equally, questions regarding how a commercial ROM works, differences between ROMs, what happens if some memory location is altered may be well received.

I'm not sure if the example questions on the proposal that you refer to would be on-topic here.  It is difficult to write a good Area51 example question as you only have the title to play with.  It would take a full, clear question to be certain.

I have seen at least three other proposals with similar but wider scope founder on Area51.  So I suspect you are right, this one won't survive and we *may* be able to give *some* of those questions a home.

Comment: *Remember that reverse engineering commercial software is explicitly off-topic under the terms of service as: Subscriber [...] will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party* -- given the number of legal exceptions that exist to allow for reverse engineering in various circumstances (including, throughout the EU, a blanket exemption to allow reverse engineering in order "to achieve the interoperability of an independently created computer program with other programs"), this shouldn't be ...

Comment: ... read as a complete prohibition of posting the results of reverse engineering.  The superuser question was explicitly about the use of reverse engineering tools for a non-legitimate purpose (i.e. software piracy), which is different to the kind of reverse engineering question we're likely to see here.